# How do you archieve to fully separate HTML/JS from PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've been working and programming for a lot of time, but this simple yet a bit complicated question is always in my mind... this will be about core and plain PHP.

I want to know how can I archieve having just HTML/js files interacting with the server without changing the extension from .html to .php as effective as possible using just the necessary requests.

for example:

I have this website that has a login page:

1. *the user types his username and passwork and its sent using AJAX to auth.php*
2. *auth.php do its thing then creates a $_SESSION if valid*
3. *the user gets redirected to dashboard.html*

Now, how do I get in every reload the current user in the frontend? I can get it in the backend just calling for example $_SESSION["username"] for the purpose of having **"welcome [the current username]"**.

The only solution I've got is to do in every redirect/refresh a AJAX request to ask for that (the request is sent to the PHP script and it echoes the session username for example) but I think this would get very heavy for the server.

what are your thoughts?

Comment: file extensions are meaningless, if you want every (or just some) *.html file(s) to go through the php parser you can

Comment: Not only adding server loads, it raises security concerns as well. Originally the request is made only in server-side, but if in HTML-PHP separation scenario, client-side has to communicate with server-side via AJAX calls. Personally, I'm against this approach, which makes a simple scenario much complicated.

Comment: @tim in Apache handler, file extension is meaningful. See `AddHandler` directive: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime.html#addhandler

Comment: Have a read of these articles ~ https://auth0.com/learn/json-web-tokens/ and https://dev.to/yos/stateless-authentication-with-json-web-tokens--km3

Comment: Same as yours: use Ajax everywhere instead, although this feels a little obsessive. But it's possible.

Comment: a HTML file and a file named *.html are not the same thing, the OP says they are

Comment: @Raptor I dont consider myself an expert at all, I dont know why but I dont feel confortable having PHP code in the HTML and echoing Userlevel-HTML code depending on the session and it does not feel right to be the proper way to do it, using ajax is much complicated but seems more organized and I think its more secure since everything its separated

Comment: Ideas such as _"the proper way"_ are highly subjective and _"more secure"_ really depends on the implementation. Ignoring for a second the red-herring about file extensions, I believe what you're asking about is akin to typical SPA (single-page-application) + API (REST) applications. Again, please read the articles I've linked above about JWTs. You might also be interested in OAuth though that's probably overkill for a single-client application

Comment: @Phil Yeah I understand what you are trying to tell me but then, if you use the Json web tokens there is no use for PHP based sessions, right? and if you are using PHP SESSIONS you must use the .php extension of the script, its a must to use them right?

Comment: With a typical JWT implementation, that would be correct since they're meant to be stand-alone though you could certainly tie an identification token to the PHP session. I mean, that's all that's stored in the PHP session cookie anyway. That being said, you'd have to jump through some hoops to automatically establish `$_SESSION` for each request

Comment: You can configure your web server to run any file extension through the PHP interpreter

Comment: Well I've tried to get the session content using ajax and aplying everything that needs it (for example "welcome username"), the thing is that in everypage it needs to do a request to the server to get that data and it seems really redundant since I bet the apache server when you load the page and have a session started  I think it is sending it